# OSS Maven - transition from Bintray

Tags: artifactory, bintray, jcenter

We're using Bintray (via JCenter) to publish our open source Android packages. JFrog are [ending Bintray](https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/) and telling us to use JFrog Platform, but the OSS option for that product is not available yet.

What am I missing?

Comment: Check https://jfrog.com/pricing/ cloud, there is a free option. You will get 2GB of free storage, 10 GB transfer/month and 200 CI/CD minutes/month

Comment: disclaimer, I am working for JFrog

Comment: @galusben this is great, but (a) still requires that I host everything using my cloud provider (paying AWS for the service) and what's even worse - (b) it doesn't give a central repo like jcenter (or Maven Central). Consumers will have to manually add the URL for my instance.

Comment: a - no additional cost. Free means free. JFrog pays all, you just pick where you want us to host it for you. The reason is mostly geo proximity to your pipelines infrastructure. b - you are right. You might want to use Maven Central for releases.

Comment: Thank you @galusben. Can you write everything as an answer, so I can accept it?